# Computational complexity of backpropagation vs. forward propagation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

I'm trying to figure out the computational complexity of one hidden-layer neural network with sigmoid activation trained on square-error loss given as such:

$$ \hat{y} = W_a \sigma(W_bx) $$

Given that $W_a$, $W_b$ are matrices.

I am trying to understand how to figure out the computational complexity of this simple neural network case, and how this can extend to multi-layer cases as well.

Comment: this is two layer, one hidden one output (w/o biases)

Comment: I should have mentioned one hidden layer, not one layer total. Thanks for pointing it out - I'll edit this in the question.